# How to create a label as showing in Screenshot

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have design a label and I haev to show as shown in Screenshot.
I have use Frame but its width is too high and if I use label background color then it show corner.[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done with button CornerRadius="20" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="White"